# Hive table column accept only key board characters,numbers and ignore control and ascii characters

Tags: regex, hadoop, plsql, hive, hiveql

Is there any regex or translate or any other expression in hive 
consider only key board characters and ignore control characters and ascii characters in Hive table?

Example: regexp_replace(option_type,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+','')
In the above expression only characters and numbers are considering but any keyboard special character data like %,&,*,.,?,.. available then i am getting output as blank.

Col: bhuvi?Where are you ?
Result: bhuviWhere are you
but i want output as bhuvi?Where are you?

like that if any special keyboard characters
comes then it will appear as is and any control or ascii character comes it will ignore.

Answer (score 1):

you should consider that various keyboard layouts (languages) have various "special" characters, like german ö ä ü or spanish Ñ (just examples - not talking about asian, hebrew or arabic keyboards).

I see two solutions:
1.) Maybe you should define a list of allowed characters and put them into a character class, so you can heavily control what is allowed, but you might exclude most languages

2.) your you might have a look into regular expression unicode classes, you can allow any "letter" `\p{L}` or "number" `\p{N}` and even punctuation `\p{P}` and **disallow** only those characters you KNOW will cause problems like control characters `\p{C}`
please see see [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) for more details about Unicode Regular Expressions

edit:

*IF* you want to stick with english only and can *assume* you will only have ASCII to allow, you can either type every key you find on your keyboard in a character class, as a not complete example: `/^[-a-zA-Z0-9,.-;:_!"§$%&]+$/`

**or**

you could use an [ASCII table](https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii%20table) to determine the range of allowed characters, in your case a assume from "space"  to "curly closing bracket" `}` and trick the character class in allowing all of them: `/^[ -}]+$/`

Comment: I want only english language and numbers and keyboard characters only.  u have any example?

Comment: ö and ß are on my keyboard and may be used in an english foreign word or name. you could specify each allowed character like `[-a-zA-Z0-9!"§$%=?]`, see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution 
regexp_replace(option_type,'[^a-zA-Z0-9*!@+-/#$%()_=/<>?\|&]+',' ')   works